# ttyS0 leaves the dialout group

Tags: permissions, virtualization, 16.10, kvm-virtualization, groups

### Issue

1. I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 as a VM.
2. In order to run it in Libvirt I added my user, and superuser, to the **dialout** group (and they're still there).
3. After a certain point I lose connection to the VM (through `virsh`).
4. A little investigation showed that `/dev/ttyS0` has left the `dialout` group, and transferred to the `tty` group:

> crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 64 Apr 9 14:32 /dev/ttyS0
>   crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 65 Apr 9 14:32 /dev/ttyS1

which means `ttyS0` doesn't have any reading permissions.

### Working on it

I tried this several times (I also used Ubuntu 14.04) and this happened in all the VMs.

What am I missing?

And how to keep `ttyS0` in the *dialout* group?

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48211/set-permission-for-dev-ttyama0-on-boot would suggest `sudo systemctl mask serial-getty@ttyS0.service`

Comment: thanks @Rinzwind, but my problem is that I lose the serial-getty... it's suppose to run this service so that systemd can find what console I'm using and open a getty for it... masking the service eliminates the option of a getty being set up - and to me (the user) it looks the same - no response on the screen :(